# Correlate Three Streams of Events for Multiple Groups With CombineLatest

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have 3 observable streams of events - in date order - (main events, events about sales, and events about customers) - each stream consists of a type of event relating to various vehicles, each event has a vehicleID and various other properties. Events can appear for one vehicle and then another vehicle etc. So basically I am trying to correlate three independent event streams together based on the VehicleID - this sounds like something that should be straightforward. I'm new to any form of complex observable programming so this proving rather difficult.

I want to call a function anytime I see a new event for a vehicle on any of the streams (I guess basically `combineLatest`). I can do it if I filter each stream only to contains events for one vehicle, so `Where`, but I can't figure out how to `GroupBy` and then get the latest of each Group. I guess I am looking to merge the streams but combineLatest on each group of vehicles.

The below would print all the objects I wish to create put only for VehcileID=1. I wish to do the below but for all vehicles. If I for looped over this with every VehcileID this would give me the output I wanted - however that doesn't seem like the hip observable - everything is a stream - state of zen that I should be aiming for.

```
Observable.CombineLatest(mainEvents.Where(a=>a.VehcileID==1),saleEventsGroup.Where(a=>a.VehcileID==1),customerEventsGroup.Where(a=>a.VehcileID==1),(main, sale, customer)=>{ 
        //Basically flattening various properties from latest state of the 3 streams for current vehicle with some mapping
        return ComplexObject(){};})       
        .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

How can I get combine the latest event for each stream for each vehicle.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? I'm only doing two streams here but the idea could easily be expanded to three

```
   [TestMethod]
   public void GroupByWithMultipleStreams()
    {
        Subject<Notification> producer = new Subject<Notification>();
        Subject<RelatedToNotification> otherThingProducer = new Subject<RelatedToNotification>();            

        Observable.Merge(
            producer.Select(n => new { Id = n.Id, notification = n, relatedNotification = (RelatedToNotification)null }),
            otherThingProducer.Select(rn => new { Id = rn.NotificationId, notification = (Notification)null, relatedNotification = rn }))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .SelectMany(obs =>
            {
                return obs.Scan(new ComplexObject() { Id = obs.Key }, (acc, input) =>
                {
                    acc.Notification = input.notification ?? acc.Notification;
                    acc.Related = input.relatedNotification ?? acc.Related;
                    return acc;
                });
            })
            .Where(result => result.Notification != null && result.Related != null) // if you only want it to fire when everything has a value
            .Subscribe(result =>
            {
                //do something with the results here
            }
            );

        producer.OnNext(new Notification() { Id = 1, Version = 1 });
        producer.OnNext(new Notification() { Id = 1, Version = 2 });
        producer.OnNext(new Notification() { Id = 2, Version = 17 });
        producer.OnNext(new Notification() { Id = 1, Version = 3 });
        producer.OnNext(new Notification() { Id = 9, Version = 0 });
        producer.OnNext(new Notification() { Id = 9, Version = 1 });
        otherThingProducer.OnNext(new RelatedToNotification() { NotificationId = 2,  SomeData = "2data" });
        otherThingProducer.OnNext(new RelatedToNotification() { NotificationId = 2, SomeData = "2data1" });
        otherThingProducer.OnNext(new RelatedToNotification() { NotificationId = 9, SomeData = "9Data" });
        producer.OnNext(new Notification() { Id = 2, Version = 1 });

    }

    class ComplexObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Notification Notification { get; set; }
        public RelatedToNotification Related { get; set; }
    }

    class Notification
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelatedToNotification
    {
        public int NotificationId { get; set; }
        public string SomeData { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Everything had a common baseclass so this got a lot simpler. It was the merge, selectmany and accumulate I wouldn't have figured out. Really appreciated!